# Android Studio could not find or load main class of "Scratch" file

Tags: java, android-studio, android-studio-3.3, scratch-file

**Update**: Below problem is remained until `Android Studio 3.4.2`.

---

I use `Android Studio 3.3` and created a `scratch` file (`File > new > Scratch File > Java`). The IDE created `scratch.java` in `~/.AndroidStudio3.3/config/scratches`:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

But when I run that scratch file ( by pressing green button near to the class name or `main` method), I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Scratch
```

I think that IDE does not make `Scratch.class` and so `Java` cannot find it. Is there a way for solving this problem and running scratch files from IDE (without using `Terminal`)?

Comment: @ankuranurag2 No it's not related. I have just tested the very same example in IntelliJ 2018.3.3, it works perfectly. It something specific to Android Studio.

Comment: I still have the same issue in Android Studio 3.3.2

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109409701

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

I just noticed that this issue was fixed in Android Studio 3.5!

---

The only way I got this to work (in Android Studio 3.4.1) is this **very dirty** approach:

1. Go to `Run` > `Edit Configurations` > `Scratch`
2. In `Before launch` at the bottom add (+) `Run External tool`
3. In External Tools popup press `+` and fill in the following `Tool Settings`

   *Name*: `Compile Scratch`

   *Program*: `javac`

   *Arguments*: `$FileName$`

   *Working Directory*: your scratch file directory
4. Press OK
5. Again in External Tools popup press `+` and fill in the following `Tool Settings`

   *Name*: `Run Scratch`

   *Program*: `java`

   *Arguments*: `$FileClass$`

   *Working Directory*: your scratch file directory
6. Press OK and Apply in Run/Debug Configurations

Weirdly this works only if you use the green arrows beside the class/main declaration. If you use the Run button in the menu this also fails.

You will still get the not found error in the `Scratch` tab of the run window. But two additional tabs will pop up (one for each external tool). In the `Run Scratch` tab you will get your output.

I personally don't like this, But it's the best workaround I came up with.

Comment: Thank you. But this does not work by pressing "green buttons". Only works if I do: `Tools > external tools > compile scrach` then `Tools > external tools > run scratch`. In this situation I prefer using `command line` directly. +1 vote for your tries.